# Cleaning up cache in AWS LIghtsail Ubuntu 18.04 Nginx server with Django apps

Tags: nginx

I am trying to clean up the cache in Ubuntu 18.04 with Nginx server with Django app.

I rebooted the instance but it is still there.

With Putty, I have been through /etc/nginx directory and couldn't find the cache folder. Where/how can I find the cache folder? How can I delete cache for a Django app in this instance simply?

I have checked /etc/nginx/ with no success.

Comment: What about the /var/nginx/cache/ path? You can also find more information in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236078/how-to-clear-the-cache-of-nginx).

Comment: Was not able to find it. That's why I am a bit confused.

Comment: try with 'sudo updatedb && sudo locate cache| grep nginx'

Comment: I used that command, was able to find related nginx in the cache default but still not able to pinpoint the cache directory for the website. I installed a Django app with gUnicorn/Nginx/Ubuntu 18.04 in AWS Lightsail. Any clue?

Comment: Does __pycache__ folders in gUnicorn make sense? django../eve/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/http/ or /app/__pycache__/?